# Big-O notation and optimizing function to include memoization?

Tags: python, optimization, big-o, memoization

I'm trying to find the smallest number evenly divisible by each integer 1-20(inclusive).  This is just me trying to improve on a practice exercise I had done before.

I wrote a function that takes in an argument  and returns the smallest number that is evenly divisible by every positive integer smaller than the argument including itself but, it is not optimized and runs relatively slow as the numbers get larger.

I was wanting to know what would the Big-O notation be for this function and why.  Then, if any, are there ways to speed this up, maybe with memoization I am not sure?

```
def divide_by_all(x):
    ## the 'pos' variable will be matched up against the argument to keep track of how many of the numbers in ##
    ## the arguments range are dividing evenly. ##
    pos = 0
    ## the 'count' variable will be set to equal the input argument, possibly
    count = x
    ## create the range of integers for the argument ##
    divs = [i for i in range(1,x + 1)]
    while pos != x:
        for i in divs:
            ## check if each 'i' in the divs list is evenly divisible ##
            ## if 'i' is not evenly divisible the 'count'(answer) is incremented, the 'pos' is set back to zero to show ##
            ## the next 'count' has no evenly divisible in numbers div yet, and then loop over the divs list starts again ##
            if count % i != 0:
                count += 1
                pos = 0
                break
            ## if 'i' is evenly divides into current 'count' increment 'pos' ##
            if count % i == 0:
                pos += 1
            ## if 'pos' == the argument 'x', meaning every number in range(x) is evenly divisible ##
            ## return 'count' ##
            if pos == x:
                return count
```

Any tips and advice welcome!

Comment: Well first hint: do you really need to check if a number is divisible by all the numbers from 1 to X? For instance from 1 to 20, do you need to check if the number is divisable by 20?

Comment: To do this more efficiently, you might be interested in the [prime factorization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).

Comment: @Zenzen , I had come up with some solutions where I would check if a number was prime or odd first.  This is I was thinking that memoization could be useful but, I am not that familiar with using that technique.

Comment: Two easy things you can do to speed this up: 1) if a number is divisible by 20, you don't need to check that it is divisible by 2, 4, 5, and 10. So work out a way to cross off numbers that don't need to be tested. 2) The largest number that it needs to be divisible by is 20. This means that you don't need to test the numbers 1..19, 21..39. i.e. the numbers you want to test will be a multiple of the largest divisor.

Comment: Well memoization is a cool thing, but starting from the beginning for instance if you checked if a number is divisible by 4 and 5 do you still need to check if it's divisible by 20? That was my point :) Also Dougal's comment might be really helpful.

Comment: @suihock I've been able to cut down the return time for '20' from 10 minutes to about 30 seconds by incrementing the count by the largest number.  I still am curious if I could return results for larger numbers in reasonable time using the prime factorization theorem

Comment: Have a look at finding the LCM using prime factorization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not that easy to give a good estimate of the asymptotic running time of this algorithm. As a ballpark estimate, it's probably somewhat less than n! (i.e. VERY slow). The problem is simply that the answer grows quickly with n : it's the product of the highest powers of the prime numbers less than n (for n=20, that would be 2^4 * 3^2 *5*7*11*13*17*19=232792560). As you check all numbers up to the answer, your running time is clearly greater than that (determining how much greater would take some work).

Memoization is not pertinent here as your alogorithm is not recursive.

Basically, this is a math problem, not an algorithmic one.

Comment: I don't think recursion is a prerequisite for making use of the memoization technique, the way I understand it, it simply avoid redundant recomputations by using a lookup table. That could be of use for iterative implementations too.

Comment: @Levon : you're right. Obviously, it's irrelevant here but memoization is not limited to avoiding redundant recursive calls.

Comment: As suggested above, think about it and use the [prime factorization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).

Comment: erm, 19 is a prime number less than 20. And it doesn't work for 5. 2*3 = 6. 6 is not divisible by 4, nor by 5.

Comment: @elssar Stupid mistake, thanks for pointing it out. I edited my answer accordingly.